# How can I send raw bytes POST request in RestSharp?

Tags: c#, restsharp

I tired sending post request in RestSharp. For some reasons, I must send a byte array.

But I tried using one way, and it didn't work.

```
restRequest.AddParameter(string.Empty, array, ParameterType.RequestBody);
```

In fact, it just send a string:

`System.Byte[]`

It seems that RestSharp call the `ToString()` method.

How can I send a byte array?

Comment: Hi. Are you sure that `c` tag in relevant here?

Comment: "But I tried using one way, and it didn't work." Can you be more specific? Did you had some error messages? Could you post a [MCVE]

Comment: @Mathieu I edited my question. If I convert the array to string ( `Encoding.UTF8.GetString()` ), the length would be longer than normal.

Answer (score 0):

You can see the extension method that will help you with this here: [RestRequestExtensions AddBody method](https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/blob/dev/src/RestSharp/Request/RestRequestExtensions.cs#L335). If request.RequestFormat == DataFormat.Binary without a Content-Type then that method should work. If the obj parameter has the type byte[], it should do what you desire.